# Imagemagick Returns error when converting into multiple sizes

Tags: shell, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am writing a shell script to output multiple image sizes and formats from a source PNG.  The script works great and outputs the correct sizes and formats but I get an error at the end of the script that I am trying to fix.  The shell script code is below:

```
convert $pic -verbose -strip \
  \( +clone             -quality 75 -write  test-output-$today-xl.jpg -write  test-output-$today-xl.webp +delete \) \
  \( +clone -resize 900 -quality 75 -write  test-output-$today-lg.jpg -write  test-output-$today-lg.webp +delete \) \
  \( +clone -resize 747 -quality 75 -write  test-output-$today-md.jpg -write  test-output-$today-md.webp +delete \) \
  \( +clone -resize 598 -quality 75 -write  test-output-$today-sm.jpg -write  test-output-$today-sm.webp +delete \) \
     +clone -resize 548 -quality 75 -write  test-output-$today-xs.jpg -write  test-output-$today-xs.webp +delete
```

Which produces this output:

```
test-input.png=>test-output-2020-12-16-xl.jpg PNG 1788x1028 1788x1028+0+0 8-bit sRGB 88171B 0.060u 0:00.065
test-input.png=>test-output-2020-12-16-xl.webp PNG 1788x1028 1788x1028+0+0 8-bit sRGB 52228B 0.180u 0:00.179
test-input.png=>test-output-2020-12-16-lg.jpg PNG 1788x1028=>900x517 900x517+0+0 8-bit sRGB 27070B 0.380u 0:00.070
test-input.png=>test-output-2020-12-16-lg.webp PNG 1788x1028=>900x517 900x517+0+0 8-bit sRGB 16648B 0.490u 0:00.070
test-input.png=>test-output-2020-12-16-md.jpg PNG 1788x1028=>747x429 747x429+0+0 8-bit sRGB 19482B 0.310u 0:00.046
test-input.png=>test-output-2020-12-16-md.webp PNG 1788x1028=>747x429 747x429+0+0 8-bit sRGB 11790B 0.350u 0:00.048
test-input.png=>test-output-2020-12-16-sm.jpg PNG 1788x1028=>598x344 598x344+0+0 8-bit sRGB 13190B 0.330u 0:00.044
test-input.png=>test-output-2020-12-16-sm.webp PNG 1788x1028=>598x344 598x344+0+0 8-bit sRGB 8134B 0.230u 0:00.033
test-input.png=>test-output-2020-12-16-xs-0.jpg[0] PNG 1788x1028=>548x315 548x315+0+0 8-bit sRGB 11719B 0.520u 0:00.073
test-input.png=>test-output-2020-12-16-xs-1.jpg[1] PNG 1788x1028=>548x315 548x315+0+0 8-bit sRGB 11719B 0.340u 0:00.047
INFO: Added frame. offset:0,0 dispose:0 blend:1
test-input.png=>test-output-2020-12-16-xs.webp[0] PNG 1788x1028=>548x315 548x315+0+0 8-bit sRGB 13732B 0.520u 0:00.075
convert:  `+delete' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3303.
```

any ideas as to why I get an error with the +delete command and also get two versions of the last jpg outputted?

Apologies if this is a simple solution, i find the imagemagick documentation a little hard to parse for specific questions.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I would approach it as follows in Imagemagic. All clones must be enclosed in parentheses. Add null: to make no other output.

```
convert $pic -verbose -strip \
  \( +clone             -quality 75 -write  test-output-$today-xl.jpg -write  test-output-$today-xl.webp +delete \) \
  \( +clone -resize 900 -quality 75 -write  test-output-$today-lg.jpg -write  test-output-$today-lg.webp +delete \) \
  \( +clone -resize 747 -quality 75 -write  test-output-$today-md.jpg -write  test-output-$today-md.webp +delete \) \
  \( +clone -resize 598 -quality 75 -write  test-output-$today-sm.jpg -write  test-output-$today-sm.webp +delete \) \
  \( +clone -resize 548 -quality 75 -write  test-output-$today-xs.jpg -write  test-output-$today-xs.webp +delete \) \
  null:
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is :

```
convert <INPUT> <OUTPUT>
```

so you must output something at the end, you can't just delete the last image.

You could end with `null:` to discard the last image, but it's better not to create it in the first place. So your best bet is:

- remove the last `+clone` and just use the input image you loaded on the first line, and
- remove the final `+delete`

---

Also,`-quality 75` is a setting, which means it remains set till you change it, so you can just put it once on the first line, rather than repeating it everywhere.

---

Also, you should double-quote `bash` variables:

```
convert "$pic" ...
```

then they'll still work when, one rainy day, your filenames have spaces in them.